# How to defer binding request until item becomes visible on the screen?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I noticed on `ListBox`es and `LongListSelector`s, that the item bound property requests are deferred until they are scrolled toward.
Is it possible to do the same thing in relation to custom positioned items in a `ScrollViewer`, such that the item doesn't make any request for its bound property values until it is scrolled toward? Is there any easy setting to make this happen automatically?
If not, then what's the simplest way of doing it otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Its called Lazy Load
 here you have an example of Lazy List:

```
public class LazyCollection<T> : IList<T>, IList, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int LOAD_THRESHOLD = 3;

    private ObservableCollection<T> _innerCollection;

    public LazyCollection(Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> fetch)
        : this(fetch, null)
    { }

    public LazyCollection(Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> fetch, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _fetch = fetch;
        _innerCollection = new ObservableCollection<T>(items ?? new T[0]);
        this.AttachEvents();
        this.HasMoreItems = true;
    }

    private void AttachEvents()
    {
        _innerCollection.CollectionChanged += (s, e) => OnCollectionChanged(e);
        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)_innerCollection).PropertyChanged += (s, e) => OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    #endregion

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CollectionChanged != null)
            this.CollectionChanged(this, e);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IList<T>
    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _innerCollection.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        _innerCollection.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _innerCollection.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Reading item {0}", index);
            return _innerCollection[index];
        }
        set { _innerCollection[index] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _innerCollection.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _innerCollection.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _innerCollection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _innerCollection.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _innerCollection.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((IList<T>)_innerCollection).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return _innerCollection.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - GetEnumerator");
        return _innerCollection.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - GetEnumerator explicit");
        return ((IEnumerable)_innerCollection).GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    #region IList
    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        return ((IList)_innerCollection).Add(value);
    }

    bool IList.Contains(object value)
    {
        return ((IList)_innerCollection).Contains(value);
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return ((IList)_innerCollection).IndexOf(value);
    }

    void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        ((IList)_innerCollection).Insert(index, value);
    }

    bool IList.IsFixedSize
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).IsFixedSize; }
    }

    bool IList.IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).IsReadOnly; }
    }

    void IList.Remove(object value)
    {
        ((IList)_innerCollection).Remove(value);
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index > this.Count - LOAD_THRESHOLD)
            {
                this.TryLoadMoreItems();
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Reading item {0} IList", index);
            return ((IList)_innerCollection)[index];
        }
        set { ((IList)_innerCollection)[index] = value; }
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        ((IList)_innerCollection).CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).IsSynchronized; }
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get { return ((IList)_innerCollection).SyncRoot; }
    }
    #endregion

    public T[] GetLoadedItems()
    {
        return _innerCollection.ToArray();
    }

    public void ResetLoadedItems(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        _innerCollection.Clear();
        foreach (var i in list)
            _innerCollection.Add(i);
        this.HasMoreItems = true;
    }

    public bool HasMoreItems { get; set; }
    private bool _isLoading = false;
    private Func<int, IEnumerable<T>> _fetch;

    private async Task TryLoadMoreItems()
    {
        if (_isLoading || !this.HasMoreItems)
            return;

        try
        {
            _isLoading = true;

            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Loading more items skip {0}", this.Count);
            List<T> items = _fetch != null ? (_fetch(Count)).ToList() : new List<T>();

            if (items.Count == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - No items returned, Loading disabled", this.Count);
                this.HasMoreItems = false;
            }

            items.ForEach(x => _innerCollection.Add(x));

            Debug.WriteLine("LazyCollection - Items added. Total count: {0}", this.Count);
        }
        finally
        {
            _isLoading = false;
        }


    }
}
public class SearchResults : LazyCollection<Verse>
{
    public SearchResults()
        : base(count => GetSearchResult(), GetSearchResult())
    {

    }

    public static int _index = 0;
    public static string CurrentSearch = "";
    public static List<Verse> AllVerses = new List<Verse>();
    private static List<Verse> GetSearchResult()
    {
        List<Verse> results = new List<Verse>();
        string lower = CurrentSearch.ToLower();
        bool resultsChanged = false;
        for (int index = _index; index < AllVerses.Count; index++)
        {
            Verse verse = AllVerses[index];
            if (verse.Content.ToLower().Contains(lower) || verse.Header.ToLower().Contains(lower))
            {
                results.Add(verse);
                resultsChanged = true;
            }
            if ((index >= (AllVerses.Count / 200) + _index || index + 1 == AllVerses.Count) && resultsChanged && (results.Count > 10 || AllVerses.Count == index + 1))
            {
                _index = index + 1;
                return results;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```